# how to search for links using telethon

Tags: python, telegram, scrape, telethon

Is there any way I can filter the messages I get from:

```
client.get_messages()
```

to a spasific pattern? (in this case links)

I can filter it after I get all the messages but if there is a way to do it earlier that would be better.

Answer (score 3):

`get_messages` (or `iter_messages`) supports `filter` argument that takes any of [`MessagesFilter`](https://tl.telethon.dev/types/messages_filter.html) constructors.

so in your case, use:

```py
await client.get_messages(chat,
    filter=telethon.types.InputMessagesFilterUrl()
)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried it and it works fine, but when I add the offset_date parameter it won't find any messages (even if there are links that were sent in the given period) maybe you know why it's happening?

the offset_date parameter works fine if I don't add the filter parameter.

Comment: Telegram offsets are very not very reliable. I would not be surprised if using `offset_date` was just not supported when searching links.

Comment: Oh ok, so do you know any other way I can search links by date?